# How does a Windows 7 backup look on the target?

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup

What folder/file structure does Windows 7 create on the target backup device?

I have an external HD and I'd like to backup my Windows 7 laptop on it. However, the external HD already has some files in it and I'm worried they'd be deleted by the backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the help:

> Backups are saved in this format: backup location\computer name\Backup Set year-month-day time. For example, if your computer name is Computer, your backup location is E, and you backed up on April 2, 2008 at 16:32:00, that backup would be located in E:\Computer\Backup Set 2008-02-04 163200.

It won't overwrite your data on the disk if there is already some. Furthermore, it would very likely never overwrite anything without asking.

Comment: Congrats on hitting 10K!